# How to store a password so that it can be passed to another site/service which is expecting a plaintext input

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, passwords

I am developing a website and I would like to allow users to use XMPP for live chat. I would like users to have the option use an existing XMPP account if they wish and store their XMPP username and password with their other account details.

Obviously, there's a big issue with just storing passwords as plain text. Is two-way encryption sufficient here? I am just at a loss for a solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "sufficient"? What's your criteria for "sufficiency"? Without a precise, unambiguous, objectively measurable specification of what, *exactly*, you mean by "sufficient", you are more or less asking for opinions on what is or isn't "sufficient", and asking for opinions is off-topic.

Comment: be ware that if you do it like this, you are potentially asking your users to violate the EULA of the chat program. Many EULAs state that the user is personal, and have some sort of lockout clause. at the least you would have to explain that this is a risk, and you need to explain that if your site is compromised their 3rd party chat account is also potentially compromised. Token exchange should be your prefered option

Comment: Do you mean that you want to store passwords to repeat login operation and therefore hashing is not possible? Not using hashing is quite dangerous.

Comment: I'll note that the security problems described in this question also plague any password manager which supports either cloud backup or multi-device sync.  I suggest reading up on how password managers solve this problem; Reputable password managers are typically quite public about how they resolve these concerns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your concerns are valid, and sadly external services don't always support desirable authentication options.

One possible method would be to encrypt the external service credentials using a key derived from your user's password with your service. When the user logs in to your service, you can decrypt the credentials and keep them in memory (with sufficient safety precautions to avoid swapping to disk etc.) while the user's session lasts. That way, the external password can only be used when the user has logged in, and database exports would be useless to hackers (at least regarding this facet.)

Of course, the user needs to trust you with their external password, as you would be able to easily store it somewhere else when they log in, and use it later for some mischief.

The devil might be in the details, so this is just an idea that you need to flesh out within the constraints of your application.

Comment: The external service is a red herring. If you're storing something that can be reliably turned into the user's password, you're storing their password. Storing their password in an encrypted manner that relies on an oracle to decrypt doesn't mean you're not storing their password, just that you've given yourself an extra hoop to jump through when it's convenient to have. The password is still stored in your DB; while the key is (theoretically) unique per-user, it's highly likely to be a _really_ weak key for most users. At best, this buys a little obscurity, which isn't security at all.

Comment: I would simplify: Any form of coding you have that will result in a clear text password will be compromised if your server is compromised. don't do it!

Comment: @minnmass saying the key is likely really weak, isn't that just the same as saying their 3rd party password is likely really weak. If they choose a weak key for your service wouldn't they choose a weak key for their service?

Comment: The (additional) problem I would see with this is that the encryption may protect against a quick data theft break in. But if your service gets compromised for a long enough time - and depending on the service a couple hours might suffice - then for all users that logged in during that time, the other account is compromised too, as the attackers can snoop out the password they have on your service and then decrypt the other one. But on the other hand, that's a risk you won't fully eliminate, it's in the concept of being able to operate on their behalf on the 3rd party service.

Comment: (could be limited though in time and scale if there would be token support etc)

Comment: @FrankHopkins: We assume the attacker knows the key derivation algorithm (because they know everything except for the secret key), so converting a cracked password into the encryption key is trivial. Thus, the encryption key's strength is proportional to the user's password's. If my password to this service is "password", that's going to be cracked in about a second by an offline attacker. Thus, they're going to have the decryption key to get my credentials for the other service (either by decrypting themselves or by calling out to the oracle) regardless of how strong that password is.

Comment: After some data collection I have determined that the userbase does not have a significant number of existing XMPP accounts to make this feature even beneficial, so in the end I will simply be creating an account for them on the local XMPP server.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution. I agree with the commentors that my approach would introduce unnecessary weaknesses, so if it's possible to avoid storing any passwords (even encrypted with user-specific keys) then that's much preferable.

Comment: Didn't some web mail services ask for account credentials (mail+password) on competing services to bring/pull mail, for the convenience of reading everything in one place, back in the day?

Comment: @minnmass: I think that's a bit unfair.  If the key is derived from the user's password (rather than from the user's hashed password), then the password is stored in the services's memory but arguably it is not stored on disk: The server's database being stolen no longer represents a compromise of all users.  Admittedly, a stolen database will still compromise weak passwords, since whoever has the database can brute force them.

Comment: @Brian: If this service stores an encrypted version of my password for that other system, it's storing my password for that other system on disk. A stolen db will provide the attacker with all they need to determine my pw for this service (presumably hash + salt) _and_ all they need to get my pw for the other service (this pw + derivation method).

Comment: @minnmass: No, that's not quite right.  The system is storing `Salt`, `Salt2`, `Hash(Password, Salt)`, and `Encrypt(Hash(Password,Salt2), Passwordlist)`.  A malicious user who steals the database will have `Hash(Password, Salt)`, `Salt`, and `Salt2`, but will be missing `Hash(Password,Salt2)`.  At that point, their best option is to brute force guess passwords to reverse `Hash(Password, Salt)`.  For passwords reversible in this manner (i.e., weaker passwords), they'll be able to retrieve `Passwordlist`.  However, this does not apply to all users.

Comment: @Brian salt2 helps. However, Encrypt(Hash(pw2, salt2)) still used pw1 to determine the key, so the encryption step isn’t really helping - getting Hash(pw2, salt2) is “trivial” once pw1 has been discovered. It’s also a good guess that pw2 will match pw1, which doesn’t help anything…

Comment: There is no pw2 involved in Hans' proposal.  `Encrypt(Hash(Password,Salt2)` and `Hash(Password, Salt)` both use the same password.  And yes, discovering this password will compromise the password list.  Hans' proposal is defending against a very narrow, specific threat: A malicious user has NOT compromised the site, but has attained a copy of the password database.  In that specific scenario, Hans' proposal will protect *some* (but not all) of the password lists.

Answer (score 19):

You really don't want to be storing passwords on your server in a reversible manner, even with encryption - if your encryption key is compromised, all passwords will be exposed. [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) is the standard solution for the use case you describe: users log in directly to the third-party service and your website gets back an access token for future use.

I'm not too familiar with XMPP, but a quick search shows that an [OAuth over XMPP](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0235.html) specification exists (it appears to be an experimental spec, but at least [one major implementation](https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/oauth/) supports it). There may also be other authentication mechanisms that let you achieve what you want without having to store the raw password.

Comment: Unfortunately, using Oauth in this case would rely on the user's server supporting it to be able to issue my platform a token. Although I use ejabberd as the local xmpp option, I can't quite rely on the user even knowing what their server supports.

Comment: @LeoGrün: It is not the user's responsibility to know what the server supports. You need to provide a user interface that allows them to choose their preferred means of authentication from a list that you support. The owners and operators of those servers, however, should know what authentication they support. If they do not, *do not allow their users into your system.*

Comment: @LeoGrün: You might have to settle for only supporting specific servers that you know can support OAuth. And then tell your users that the other servers do not offer a secure way of integrating with your website. Storing raw passwords is too risky considering that even the origin server likely only has a hash and not the actual password.

Answer (score 2):

Never store passwords, for any reason. Not in plaintext, not in reversible encryption. The answer to your question is that you need your third-party service to support a reasonable authentication process, and if they don't then you simply cannot use them.

1. Storing passwords exposes yourself to liability. Normal password hashing prevents anyone, including you or a system administrator, from getting those passwords. If passwords are stored reversibly, then you have to trust everyone in your organization not to abuse that power, and users can credibly claim that you are a possible accomplice if they ever get hacked.
2. Storing passwords poorly makes you a target. Thieves and hackers like easy targets, and failing to obey best practices paints a great big bullseye on you and your organization.
3. Think about your reputation. It will also set off huge red flags when your security conscious users are asked to put their third-party password into your site.
4. Storing passwords threatens your users. Users are notoriously bad at password security, so you're not just protecting their XMPP account, you're protecting their bank account and everything else.

The accepted way to do this is OAuth, as has been said. Some services will provide their own third party authentication solution. Outside of this, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

There's a big issue with storing passwords in this scenario, at all.

In this scenario you didn't issue their identity.

Likewise, you are not on the hook to verify their identity.

Additionally, you are only partially running on the user's computer.

Therefor you're assuming a liability that is traditionally managed only by the user and the issuer of the identity.

You've given anyone seeking to compromise that identity another line of attack, for little to no perceptible benefit other than perhaps moderate convenience.

This is not fundamentally impossible to do securely, but it is something you probably shouldn't be trying to do yourself without a lot of experience in the arena of cybersecurity systems design, and it's a lot of risk to take on for a convenience feature.